# How to vertically and horizontally center slick slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I need my slick slider carousel to be completely centered in whatever browser someone is viewing it in. In other words, whether your viewing it in desktop chrome or an iPhone X Max the slider is positioned in the middle of the viewport. the slider is stuck to the top of the page.

I've tried every solution i could find but whatever i try the carosuel remains stuck to the top of the page.

```
this is the first method i tried https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/281
I tried to fiddle with what i found in both slick.css and slick-theme.css and still couldnt figure it out.

.slick-slide.c {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float:none;
}
```

```
 My current style.css 

#wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
  }

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}
body.Site{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  outline: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: blue;

}
main.Site-content{


}
footer {

  height: 120px;
  background: red;

}

.barcode{
font-family: 'Libre Barcode 39', cursive;
font-size: 2vw;
}



.slider {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  background: green;

}

.player {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  background: purple;
  outline: 0;
}


I expect my slider to remain centered vertically and horizontally within its viewport.
```

Comment: can you share live example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55593181/how-to-vertically-center-a-div

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you can use to center your slider horizontally and vertically. As there are some issues in adding external libraries in the code snippet, I have created a codepen for you. You can refer to this [link](https://codepen.io/ArunK_UI/pen/YMQaaW):

```js
 
 $('.slider-nav').slick({
   slidesToShow: 3,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   asNavFor: '.slider-for',
   dots: true,
   focusOnSelect: true
 });
```

```css
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
.main {
  font-family:Arial;
  width:500px;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
h3 {
    background: #fff;
    color: #3498db;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  
  <div class="slider slider-nav">
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT NOTE: Please check the codepen link instead of snippet result for the final result.